# Fastest running scripting language for use with Java

Tags: java, scripting

I would like to know the best (fastest) scripting language for use in Java. I don't much care if it takes long to load (as long as it is a one time load), as opposed to how fast it runs. I am currently using Jython (python) but I would like something faster.

Comment: as a rule of thumb (fast to write) != (fast to execute)

Comment: as another rule of thumb, efficiency of your algorithm\program is a lot more important then the language\ environment\ interpreter speed

Comment: @Hellfrost "I'm sorry I wrote such a long letter, but I didn't have time to write a short one." - Blaise Pascal... If only he knew how much that would apply to our profession!

Comment: @corsiKa and to the language named after him!

Answer (score 4):

There's already a lot of benchmarks and discussions on this.
While I don't give a lot of credit (none) to benchmarking. The top 2 contenders are (listed in order of performance speed):

- Scala
- Groovy++

I've tried both and their not the same in my use cases. Scala came out much faster than groovy++ (again.. this is MY use cases not and may show differently in your use cases). Scala was almost native java speeds.

Groovy (not Groovy++), Closure, JRuby are all really slow.
Groovy and JRuby run approximately 8 times slower on simple algorithms compared to the java versions even after a decent amount of warmup.

I can't guarantee that you would get the same numbers that I did but this would be a decent order to try them in.

Comment: +1 The only benchmarks that matter to me are the ones I've run on MY code in MY environment with MY stupid users slowing it down. The others are nice for academic exercises, and I'm happy to hear what other people have done to give me guidance, but at the end of the day, it's just a bunch of numbers that mean nothing to the program I'm trying to optimize.

Answer (score 1):

Groovy is a very good scripting language that plays very nicely with Java.

That being said, Java can run any scripting language via the command line, or it could run any other program if you wanted it to. So I would focus less on the Java side of it and more on the 'faster' side of it.

There's nothing from stopping you to writing a C++ program to compiled code and calling that.

Further, what profiling tests have you done with Jython/python? How slow is it that it doesn't meet your expectations? Is it causing problems? Is it perhaps in the python script?

Comment: Well, it does take some time to execute the script (I haven't actually logged the time length) I can get some statistics for you in a moment. Also, I would like a language that can run java methods, and use java classes as variables.

Comment: Hmm.. have you considered Java? It runs methods and uses classes and variables quite efficiently!

Comment: And, don't take this the wrong way, but if you haven't profiled the code, you don't have a problem. Your primary objective should be to find out what part of the script is slowing you down. Further, establish what you think is an appropriate time for it to be running in.

Comment: It took 350ms to run this: http://pastebin.com/8z05m5a3 . The methods called, really are not big.

Comment: How much of that was the startup time? If you were to do it 1000 times, would it take 350 seconds? And, why is this in a script and not simply in Java code?

Comment: And what is `ActionSender` does this make a network call? Because I could see transactional overhead being significant there.

Comment: I have tested this apposed to it in java, and it is at least 3 times slower, and has been as much as 10 times slower

Comment: @glowcoder, if someone speaks about "scripting language" in this context then he means a guest language that is used to script the current running application (not a forked out externel process written in a scripting language). Connor, Jythons is very slow. It is not even compiled to proper JVM bytecode but to its own. Groovy however itegrates very good. Speed might be an issue as well, so consider to load scripts only once and reuse them.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried programming in Java?

You can write some of the performance critical functionality in Java, and leave most of the code in the scripting language of your choice.

Answer (score 0):

Java since version 7 has support for normal compiling at runtime, if SDK is on the path, javax.tools.JavaCompiler

Answer (score 0):

LuaJIT    https://github.com/gareins/dynamic_benchmarks

The above benchmarks show LuaJIT to be very fast but it still qualifies as a dynamic language.